# telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo() returns null

Tags: java, android, gsm, lte

I want to get some informations from phone's service mode into application. Example

I do have a Permission granded.
What is the simplest way to get service mode info into variables? 
(Lac Cell ID etc for LTE WCDMA and LTE)

```
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        List<CellInfo> cellList = telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo();
        if (cellList != null) {
            for (final CellInfo cell : cellList) {
                if (cell instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
                    CellInfoGsm cellInfoGsm = (CellInfoGsm) cell;
                    int a = (cellInfoGsm.getCellIdentity().getLac());
                    TextView textviewdupka = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewdupka);
                    textviewdupka.setText("cid: "+a);
                } else if (cell instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "LTE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "other", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "null CellList", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

right nowe telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo() returns null for this example.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/3c3d33a/tests/tests/telephony/src/android/telephony/cts/CellInfoTest.java

Comment: Visit the link, maybe it can help you out.